# SimpleCart js - display item options in cart?

Tags: jquery, simplecart

For the life of me I can't figure out how to get the options I created for a product to be displayed in the cart. They pass just fine to Paypal! I've spent all day searching for an answer (including ALL the issues on GitHub for simpleCart) and I'm stuck.

I just want the color and size to show up in the cart. I managed to get a header for size and color in the cart, but I don't know where I should be looking for the actual data.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">              
                    <h2 class="item_name"> MyPakage Weekday </h2>
                    <p> The first thing you put on to start your day should be a pair of these ultra comfortable MyPakage underwear. You'll thank us later. Put your most vital equipment in these premium underwear - no adjusting needed - and experience a new level of comfort. <br />
                    Features include:
                            <ul>
                            <li>Special blend of Modal and Spandex</li>
                            <li>Breathable and moisture-wicking (50% more than cotton)</li>
                            <li>Wrinkle free and shrink proof</li>
                            <li>Resistance to pilling from friction</li>
                            <li>Patented KeyHole comfort technology</li>
                            <li>No seams in critical areas</li>
                            <li>Seamless tag</li>
                            <li>Hand-stitched in critical areas</li>
                            </ul>
                    Note: For Charcoal/Orange, Seafoam/Orange, and Cobalt/Yellow there are no sizes 28-30 available. <br />
                    Size: <select class="item_size">
                        <option value="2830"> 28-30 </option>
                        <option value="3032"> 30-32 </option>
                        <option value="3436"> 34-36 </option>
                        <option value="3840"> 38-40 </option>
                    </select> <br />
                    Color: <select class="item_color">
                        <option value="Black Black Red"> Black Black Red</option>
                        <option value="Black Black Lime"> Black Black Lime</option>
                        <option value="Black Purple"> Black Purple</option>
                        <option value="Black Lime"> Black Lime</option>
                        <option value="Grey Blue"> Grey Blue</option>
                        <option value="Grey Yellow"> Grey Yellow</option>
                        <option value="White White Red"> White White Red</option>
                        <option value="Black Red"> Black Red</option>
                        <option value="Black Blue"> Black Blue</option>
                        <option value="Black Green"> Black Green</option>
                        <option value="White Red"> White Red</option>
                        <option value="White Black"> White Black</option>
                        <option value="Orange Charcoal"> Charcoal Orange</option>
                        <option value="Seafoam Orange"> Seafoam Seafoam Orange</option>
                        <option value="Cobalt Yellow"> Cobalt Cobalt Yellow</option>
                    </select><br>
                    Quantity: <input type="text" value="1" class="item_Quantity"><br>
                    Price: <span class="item_price">$25.00</span><br>
                <a class="item_add" href="javascript:;"> Add to Cart </a></p>
```

Here is my cart columns (gives me the header values and that's it.) I know I'm missing the piece that grabs the data, but I don't know where/what to do.

```
cartStyle               : "table",
                cartColumns         : [
                    { attr: "name", label: "Name" },
                    { attr: "item_size", label: "Size" },
                    { attr: "item_color", label: "Color" },
                    { attr: "price", label: "Price", view: 'currency' },
                    { attr: "quantity", label: "Qty" },
                    { view: "decrement", label: false },
                    { view: "increment", label: false },
                    { attr: "total", label: "SubTotal", view: 'currency' },
                    { view: "remove", text: "Remove", label: false },
```

Thank you in advance. My brain is fried!

Comment: I don't think you need to add "item_" as attr labels in your columns object.

Comment: So if I just remove the attr labels that will input the data? Thank you.

Comment: Yea, remove the "item_" and you'll be good to go!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change these

```
{ attr: "size", label: "Size" },
{ attr: "color", label: "Color" },
```